# Adding HUD to GameScene scene (Cocos2d)

Tags: objective-c, scope, cocos2d-iphone

So here's the situation: I have a `GameScene` class as my main scene for my game. In my implementation, I have `+(id)scene`, and my `appdelegate` runs the game by using `runWithScene` and calling that method.

Similarly, I've created a `ControlLayer` class. I've written it as a `CCLayer` subclass, and my plan was to add the `ControlLayer` over the main `GameScene`. It has `+(id)control` to start it off.

Now, I'm not exactly sure how to put this all together. I've tried creating an `ControlLayer` object in `+(id)scene` and using `addChild:z:` to put my `ControlLayer` over. The joysticks I have move when I touch them, as they should. The problem I seem to be running into is making my player move.

I've scheduled `GameScene` to call its `checkJoystick:` method every frame. However, since I declared the `ControlLayer` object in `+(id)scene`, obviously `checkJoystick` can't access my `ControlLayer` object. I've also added a `ControlLayer` object in my header, but obviously     `+(id)scene` can't access that either. I've tried changing `+(id)scene` to `-(id)scene`, this fixes scope issues but causes errors.

Basically, I think my question is: How do I declare this `ControlLayer` object in my `GameScene` so that the entire class can use it? Perhaps this would be in `init`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  In your GameScene class add a member variable in the .h file for the ControllerLayer class.

in GameScene.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) ControllerLayer* myControllerLayer; // don't forget to synthesize in Gamescene implementation
```

Then in your GameScene +scene method, do something like

```
CCScene* scene = [CCScene node];

GameScene* gameSceneLayer = [GameScene node];
[scene addChild:gameSceneLayer];

ControllerLayer* controllerLayer = [ControllerLayer node];
[scene addChild:controllerLayer];

gameSceneLayer.myControllerLayer = controllerLayer;
```

Now your GameScene has access to the ControllerLayer via the myControllerLayer property

NOTE:  There are a couple of other ways to solve your problem for example use [scene addChild:z:tag:] and then use getChildByTag... etc